# Get tuple from double "for" loop in Python

Tags: python

The code like:

```
for x in ['a','b','c']:
    for y in [1,2,3]:
```

I just want get the tuple like:

```
("a",1)
("b",2)
("c",3)
```

Comment: `zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` returns `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`